# How to use Selenium WebDriver to Download APK Files

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriver-io

I am trying to download an `.apk` file using SeleniumWebDriver on FireFox.

I have set the profile to `auto-save`, but when I click the `.apk` file download link, it opens the *download confirmation dialogue*.

How should I proceed moving forward?

Here is my code:

```js
FirefoxProfile fprofile = new FirefoxProfile();
fprofile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
fprofile.setPreference( "browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false );
fprofile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", "D:\\WebDriverdownloads");
fprofile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
fprofile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",
"application/vnd.android.package-archive;"); //MIME Type for APK files
driver = new FirefoxDriver(fprofile);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no easy way to download files with Selenium because browsers use native dialogs. Check this [link](http://blog.codecentric.de/en/2010/07/file-downloads-with-selenium-mission-impossible/).

[AutoIT](http://joychester.blogspot.com/2011/01/deal-with-file-download-in-webdriver-by.html) was helpful for me, hope it helps you too.

Comment: AutoIT is windows specific ONLY. Once you open you tests on mac they'll be failing

Answer (score 0):

In my code, I just have following preferences and it works fine. Looks like you do have these options already.

```
   "browser.download.folderList": 2,
   "browser.download.dir": "/Users/nilesh",
   "browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk": "text/csv"
```

If you search online, people will be posting bunch of solutions using AutoIT and Robot class. I strongly recommend you avoid that. AutoIT to my knowledge is windows only. My experience with Robot didn't give consistent results. So both solutions are flimsy and brittle.

Also if you care about supporting multiple browsers, you would have to deal with this problem on per browser basis and NOT just firefox. I recommend you reading [this blog](http://ardesco.lazerycode.com/index.php/2012/07/how-to-download-files-with-selenium-and-why-you-shouldnt/) which describes how to download files in Selenium and why you shouldn't. Author of the blog provides a solution in Java on querying for the file using a HTTP Get request. That's the best way to deal with this problem if you want to support multiple browsers.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I agree with you, infact **CSV TXT PDF and XLS files are perfectly downloading** with my code but when i do the same for **APK, it doesn't work**.

Comment: @BSCSStudent glad it helped. If it makes sense please accept the answer.

Comment: Sir I said that MY CODE is working with CSV etc formats BUT I NEED TO DOWNLOAD .APK FILE WHICH IS **NOT WORKING**...!!